# Adverb phrase vs adjective phrase …

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

Take this money and buy some bandages **in the shop**.

Here **in the shop** — acts as a adjective or adverb.

Because **in the shop** indicates place, it also modifies **bandages** so it can be adjective-like. So plz explain the grammar rule if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sentence, the phrase "in the shop" only modifies "buy", not "bandages".

But let's change the sentence a bit:

> Take this money and buy **the** bandages in the shop.

This new sentence is ambiguous, and could either mean to go into the shop and buy the bandages, or it could mean to buy "*the bandages **which are** in the shop*". In that second case, "in the shop" is a *reduced relative clause* that modifies "bandages" like an adjective.

This is not the case in your original sentence, however, because "some bandages" means *we're not specifying which bandages*. This means we know that "in the shop" is not a reduced relative clause, so it only modifies "buy", not bandages.